# Malayalam font support in Windows Phone 8 Application

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am new to Windows Phone 8 Application, and I am trying to develop an application which displays text in Malayalam font. I used

```
  <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock"  Text= "&#3381;&#3391;&#3366;&#3405;&#3375;&#3375;&#3405;&#3349;&#3405;&#3349;&#3405;  " TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="25" FontFamily="/PhoneApp1;component/Fonts/FontName.ttf#FontName" />
```

It shows text " വിദ്യയ്ക്ക്  " in Design mode. But when i run it it shows text in &#[3381]; .what should i do to show Malayalam font . I have set Build Action as Content for font file. Any one knows the answer please help me
Regards,
Pranav J Dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this to display my own font:

```
<TextBlock Text="&#3381;" 
   FontFamily="/Assets/FontName.ttf#FontName"/>
```

The font itself is located within the Assets folder just below the root. The font file has build action "Content" and "Do no copy" to output directory.

I tried a similar approach as you before, but this did not work too. That's why I came up with this solution after some try/error attempts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my font is unicode and its not displaying correctly.

Comment: My font as well. The changes with the fontFamily definition made the difference in my case. I started with the definition you are using and it did not work too. Then I changed the FontFamily property to what I am using and it works fine.

Comment: i will try and if succes, will let you know

Comment: No way. I just converted Unicode to Ascii font and apply that font as you mentioned and it works fine.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad that it helped :-) Maybe mark as correct answer?